# Apify cheerio scraper stops even with urls in the queue

Tags: web-scraping, cheerio, apify

here is the scenario, I'm using the [cheerio scraper](https://apify.com/apify/cheerio-scraper) to scraper a website containing real estate announces.

Each announce has the link to the next announce so before scrapint the current page I add the next page in the request queue.
What it happens always at certain and a random point is that the scraper stops without any reason, even if in the queue there is the next page to scrape (I add the image).

Why does this happens since there is still a pending request in the queue?
Many thanks

**Here is the message I get:**

```
2021-02-28T10:52:35.439Z INFO  CheerioCrawler: All the requests from request list and/or request queue have been processed, the crawler will shut down.
2021-02-28T10:52:35.672Z INFO  CheerioCrawler: Final request statistics: {"requestAvgFailedDurationMillis":null,"requestAvgFinishedDurationMillis":963,"requestsFinishedPerMinute":50,"requestsFailedPerMinute":0,"requestTotalDurationMillis":22143,"requestsTotal":23,"crawlerRuntimeMillis":27584,"requestsFinished":23,"requestsFailed":0,"retryHistogram":[23]}
2021-02-28T10:52:35.679Z INFO  Cheerio Scraper finished.
```

**Here the request queue:**

[image: request queue details]

**Here the code**

```js
async function pageFunction(context) {
    const { $, request, log } = context;

    // The "$" property contains the Cheerio object which is useful
    // for querying DOM elements and extracting data from them.
    const pageTitle = $('title').first().text();

    // The "request" property contains various information about the web page loaded. 
    const url = request.url;
    
    // Use "log" object to print information to actor log.
    log.info('Scraping Page', { url, pageTitle });

    // Adding next page to the queue
    var baseUrl = '...';
    if($('div.d3-detailpager__element--next a').length > 0)
    {
        var nextPageUrl = $('div.d3-detailpager__element--next a').attr('href');
        log.info('Found another page', { nextUrl: baseUrl.concat(nextPageUrl) });
        context.enqueueRequest({ url:baseUrl.concat(nextPageUrl) });
    }
    
    // My code for scraping follows here
    
    return { /*my scaped object*/}
 }
```

Comment: My first thought is that you are missing await keyword somewhere. Is is possible to share (partially) the code?

Comment: You probably need to ask apify support about things like this.

Comment: @LukášKřivka I'm using the example code, the code is pretty straightforward, firsl line I check the presence of the a with the class of the next announce, if it exists I add it to the queue, then I do my extraction, I do it in this way exactly to avoid any problem and at the very top so if there is an exception I will be sure that it will keep extracting the next page

Comment: @ollie10 Really hard to tell without seeing the code. just check you are not missing awaits

Comment: @LukášKřivka I edited the question adding the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Missing await

`await context.enqueueRequest`

Comment: Ok, I've got it, I copied it from documentation where there was no await... thanks!